# Couldn't find the x path of filter in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

Tried this:
WebElement searchDropdown = driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='selected']");
        Select searchFilter = new Select(searchDropdown);
        searchFilter.selectByVisibleText("Subscription");

But it didn't work.

Comment: 1. What do you mean "didnt work"? Either there was some exception or the code executed but nothing happened? 2. Is that page public available so that we could test?

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Site url: http://www.myfonts.com/home and this is the exception: 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'NOI-NAMITAJ-W10', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:47)
 at SelectFilter.main(SelectFilter.java:22)

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to get `UnexpectedTagNameException` as when you try to create an object of `Select` class on an element, webdriver explicitly checks the tag-name, if it is not `select`(which is in your case), it throws an `UnexpectedTagNameException`.

See the implementation code below:

```
if (null == tagName || !"select".equals(tagName.toLowerCase())) {
      throw new UnexpectedTagNameException("select", tagName);
}
```

Now coming to your case, what you can do instead is:

- Click on All fonts, then click on Subscription.
- Create a composite click mentioned above using `Actions` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this below xpath. This will work.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'All fonts')]
```

Moreover from your code, I assume when clicking on the All fonts displays the select dropdown. From your code it seems you haven't clicked on the all fonts. Try clicking on the same Xpath you used and try it.